# Having trouble concatenating with Arcade across fields and having No Data when all columns are empty

Tags: popup, array, arcade

I have data that needs to be in a pop-up that is contained across several fields.  If the fields have no data, I would like the pop-up to say "No Aviation Resources".  Here is what I have so far, it works except for the "No Aviation Resources" part....

```
var i = 0;
var features = [];

function addvalue(feat) {
    if (!IsEmpty(feat)) {
        features[i++] = feat;
    }
}
//Add your values
addvalue($feature.AirAttackSearch);
addvalue($feature.AirtankerSearch);
addvalue($feature.LeadPlaneSearch);
addvalue($feature.ReconSearch);
addvalue($feature.SmokejumperAircraftSearch);
addvalue($feature.RotorWIngSearch);
addvalue($feature.UASSearch);

IIf(IsEmpty(features), "No Aviation Resources", Concatenate(features, ";"))
```

Comment: Are you using Arcade with ArcGIS Pro or ArcGIS Online?

Answer (score 1):

As per the Arcade documentation for IsEmpty:

IsEmpty( value ) -> Boolean
Returns true if the provided value is null or an empty string (e.g. ''). **Returns false for all other cases, including empty arrays** and dictionaries.

https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/logical_functions/#isempty

Check for a zero sized array instead

```
IIf(count(features)==0, "No Aviation Resources", Concatenate(features, ";"))
```